# How to show Datatable with ajax post data request?

Tags: datatable, datatables

This is my HTML Form

```
<form id="inputform" action="#" method="post">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tgl_awal" placeholder="Start Date..." value="2019-05-01" />
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tgl_akhir" placeholder="End Date..." value="2019-05-15" />
</form>
```

This is my Jquery code

```
 $("#inputform").submit(function(){
        $('#demo-dt-basics').dataTable( {
            "ajax": {
                "url" : "controller/menu_autodebet.php",
                "type" : "POST",
                "data" : function ( ) {
                    return JSON.stringify({
                        tgl_awal: $("#tgl_awal").val(),
                        tgl_akhir: $("#tgl_akhir").val()
                    });
                }
            },
            "columns" : [
                { "data" : "co_brand" },
                { "data" : "tanggal" },
                { "data" : "waktu" },
                { "data" : "no_mc" },
                { "data" : "nama" },
                { "data" : "nomor_peserta" }
            ]
        });
 });
```

And here is the data from php

```
{"resultCode":"00","resultDesc":"Success","data":{"1":{"co_brand":"jkn","tanggal":"18/03/2019","waktu":"09:16:49","no_mc":"082245326737","nama":"xxxxxx","nomor_peserta":"889980000001118201"},"2":{"co_brand":"jkn","tanggal":"25/03/2019","waktu":"07:34:31","no_mc":"08119235344","nama":"Muhaaa Ryuu","nomor_peserta":"899880172403268601"}}}
```

The problem is, i can't show the entire data that i've gained from my ajax request. When i use code above, the datatable still showing "No data available in table".

Please help me to figure it out which code that messed up

Comment: Try to get rid of indexes inside `data`, let it be array of objects rather than object nesting other objects.

Comment: Did you mean the `data` from the php response ?

Comment: Yes, make it look like `"data":[{"co_brand":"jkn",...},{...},...]`

Answer (score 0):

Your data function in the ajax request is not returning the response back to Datatables.

You would write a normal ajax loaded Datatable as such

```
$('#demo-dt-basics').DataTable({
ajax: {
    url: 'controller/menu_autodebet.php',
    dataSrc : ''
},
columns: [
    { "data" : "co_brand" },
    { "data" : "tanggal" },
    { "data" : "waktu" },
    { "data" : "no_mc" },
    { "data" : "nama" },
    { "data" : "nomor_peserta" }        
]
});
```

If you wanted to retrieve the ajax response as well, you would do it like so

```
$('#demo-dt-basics').DataTable({
ajax: {
    url: 'controller/menu_autodebet.php',
    dataSrc : function (result) {
        //Process result here (e.g. assign to variable)
        //You must return the result of the ajax call back to the Datatable constructor
        return result;
    }
},
columns: [
    { "data" : "co_brand" },
    { "data" : "tanggal" },
    { "data" : "waktu" },
    { "data" : "no_mc" },
    { "data" : "nama" },
    { "data" : "nomor_peserta" }        
]
});
```

This sends the result of the ajax query back to the Datatables constructor, without which, the data will not load.